# Как правильно сделать запрос MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть задача, нужно выбрать 5 записей с таблички profile c максимальным рейтингом.

```
SELECT * FROM profile WHERE raiting > 0 LIMIT 5;
```

Рейтинг может быть от 0 до 5.0. Не могу сообразить как правильно сделать такой запрос

Comment: order by __________________

Comment: WHERE raiting >= 0 AND raiting =< 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM profile ORDER BY raiting DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: постарайтесь, пожалуйста, писать более развёрнутые ответы.

Answer (score 3):

Вот так, со всеми запрошенными условиями, дальше думаю сам разберешься

```
SELECT * 
FROM profile 
WHERE raiting > 0 and raiting < 5.0 -- условие вхождения
ORDER BY raiting DESC -- сортировка по убыванию
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно добавить сортировку `ORDER BY raiting DESC`

`ORDER BY` - конструкция для сортировки, `DESC` - обратная сортировка (`ASC` - прямая)